# Request to Apostrophe’s server

Tags: javascript, request, apostrophe-cms

I’d like to make a request in my j=Javascript code to the Apostrophe’s server (like PUT, POST…). I did that but it does not work:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <div class="main-content">
    <h3>Hello world!
        {% if not data.user %}
        <a class="login-link" href="/login">Login</a>
        {% endif %}
    </h3>
    <p>This is a very bare bones Apostrophe project. Now, get to work and make a real website!</p>
    </div>
    {{
        apos.area(data.page, 'body', {
        widgets: {
            'apostrophe-images': {
                size: 'full'
            },
            'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                toolbar: [ 'Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink' ],
                styles: [
                    { name: 'Heading', element: 'h3' },
                    { name: 'Subheading', element: 'h4' },
                    { name: 'Paragraph', element: 'p' }
                ]
            }
        }
    })

    self.apos.tasks.add(self.__meta.name, 'insert-stuff', function(apos, argv, callback) {
        var req = self.apos.tasks.getReq();
        return self.find(req, { cool: true }).toArray().then(function(err, pieces) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
        });
    };

}}
{% endblock %}
```

When I run the script (going to localhost:3000), I receive an error in my console. I have the error :

```
e.stack: Template render error: (apostrophe-pages:pages/home.html) [Line 34, Column 3]
expected variable end
at Object.exports.prettifyError (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:34:15)
at new_cls.render (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:469:27)
at Object.self.renderBody (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-templates\index.js:309:47)
at Object.self.renderForModule (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-templates\index.js:176:19)
at Object.self.render (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-module\index.js:173:34)
at Object.self.renderPageForModule (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-templates\index.js:666:28)
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-module\index.js:349:31
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:726:13
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:269:32
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:723:17
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:167:37
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
at iterate (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:260:24)
at Object.async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:281:9)
:: 2018-08-17T10:43:23+0200: template error at /
Current user: admin
{ Template render error: (apostrophe-pages:pages/home.html) [Line 34, Column 3]
expected variable end
at Object.exports.prettifyError (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:34:15)
at new_cls.render (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:469:27)
at Object.self.renderBody (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-templates\index.js:309:47)
at Object.self.renderForModule (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-templates\index.js:176:19)
at Object.self.render (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-module\index.js:173:34)
at Object.self.renderPageForModule (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-templates\index.js:666:28)
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-module\index.js:349:31
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:726:13
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:269:32
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:723:17
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:167:37
at C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
at iterate (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:260:24)
at Object.async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (C:\Windows\System32\test-project\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:281:9) name: ‘Template render error’ }
```

Comment: did you double check your syntax? are you missing a `)` for the end of `self.apos.tasks.add` ?

Comment: You have tried to write JavaScript inside a Nunjucks template file. Also the code example you started from is a command line task, not an Express route. And you don't have any front-end JavaScript here that attempts to communicate with that route, if it existed. I will prepare a sample in the apostrophe-samples repo that demonstrates creating a route and communicating with it from the browser.

Comment: This tutorial does demonstrate creating routes and communicating with them correctly, but a simpler sample just of that feature would be good: https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html